# Semidirect product defined by a non-trivial abstract homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let's say we are given two abelian subgroups, $H$ and $K$ of a group $G$. It is obvious that the semi-direct product is abelian (i.e. the direct product) if the homomorphism $\phi: K \to Aut(H)$ is trivial. However, let us say we can show there exists a non-trivial homomorphism. The proofs of some classification theorems seem to imply that it is  necessarily true that under a non-trivial homomorphism the semi-direct product will be non-abelian.

The book uses specific example (i.e. conjugation) where the non-abelian (ness) of the semi-direct product under a non-trivial homomorphism is visible by computation. However, in a more abstract setting (i.e. no idea how $k$ is acting on $H$) why is it necessarily the case that if non-trivial homomorphisms exist, they will give rise to a non-abelian semi-direct product?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\phi: K \to \text{Aut}(H)$ is non-trivial, there is some $k \in K$, and some $h' \in H$ such that $\phi_k(h') \neq h'$.

Now consider the products (for any $h \in H$): $(h,k)\ast(h',e_K)$ and $(h',e_K)\ast(h,k)$.

The first is $(h\phi_k(h'),k)$, while the second is $(h'\phi_{e_K}(h),k) = (h'h,k) = (hh',k)$ (since $H$ is abelian, and $\phi_{e_K}$ is the identity automorphism).

By supposition, $\phi_k(h') \neq h'$, so $h\phi_k(h') \neq hh'$, so these two products are two distinct elements of $H \rtimes_{\phi} K$, and thus the semi-direct product cannot be abelian.